# Handling multiple listeners for multiple clients

Tags: node.js, event-handling

I'm trying to build a chat service and make the clients recive feed about what is happening in their chat rooms via a webhook they define

Let's say that this is the code to listen for a new message on a client chat room, this code listen for just the user1 chat room,

```
const client = new Client({id:"user1"});
client.on("message:new",(message) => {
   // send a POST request to the user webhook with the message 
})
client.init()
```

If I have 10K users in my DB (10K chat rooms)

- How can I add listeners for all of them taking in consideration the resource managment and high avaliablity of the service ?

Comment: If you have 10K users with 10K chat rooms, you can afford 10K listeners.

Comment: I'm asking about the way of how can I do it ? Should I loop over all the users and init the listeners and That's it ? also I'm worried about the resource managment and scalling too

Comment: If you are using an iteration to create the clients, you could add the listeners in there. The rest depends on what your `Client` is.